# HTML form + PHP does not match

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am facing difficulties in creating a form for a random website.
I am using HTML and a file in PHP for developing the same, codes below:

File PHP:

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  

<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="txt/html; charset=iso-8859-1">  
</head>  

<body>  

<?php  

     $mensagem = "Nome: ".$_POST['nome']." \n";  
     $mensagem = "Email: ".$_POST['email']." \n";  
     $mensagem = "Assunto: ".$_POST['assunto']." \n";  
     $mensagem = "Mensagem: ".$_POST['mensagem'].  

     mail("helpcelere@gmail.com", "Suporte Célere", $mensagem);  

?>  

</body>  
</html>
```

File HTML:

```
<form action="contato_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formulario_contato" id= "formulario_contato" align="center">  
    <input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" form="formulario_contato" placeholder="Nome" size="35" />  
    <br />  
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" form="formulario_contato" placeholder="E-mail" size="35" />  
    <br />  
    <input name="assunto" type="text" id="assunto" form="formulario_contato" placeholder="Assunto" size="35" />  
    <br />   
    <textarea name="mensagem" cols="45" rows="5" id="mensagem" form="formulario_contato" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem"></textarea>  
    <br />  
    <button type="submit" form="formulario_contato" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>  
  </form>
```

When I press the send button, it points to the "contact_file.php" page, however, the email with the filled fields of the form does not arrive in the email described "helpcelere@gmail.com".

can anybody help me? Thankful!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this whole block failed for 2 reasons.

```
 $mensagem = "Nome: ".$_POST['nome']." \n";  
 $mensagem = "Email: ".$_POST['email']." \n";  
 $mensagem = "Assunto: ".$_POST['assunto']." \n";  
 $mensagem = "Mensagem: ".$_POST['mensagem'].
```

You're overwriting your `$mensagem` variable without concatenating using dots `.`, and it's also missing closure being a missing semi-colon `;` which would have thrown a parse error having error reporting set to catch and display.

It should read as

```
 $mensagem = "Nome: ".$_POST['nome']." \n";  
 $mensagem .= "Email: ".$_POST['email']." \n";  
 $mensagem .= "Assunto: ".$_POST['assunto']." \n";  
 $mensagem .= "Mensagem: ".$_POST['mensagem'];
```

PHP's error reporting would have been of some help here.

- https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

A note on the mail headers. You should use all 4 parameters and using a valid
email `From: email@example.com` address, otherwise it may get flagged as spam or rejected altogether.

Consult the manual:

- https://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

If I were you, I would check against any empty fields. Otherwise, you stand at getting a lot of blank emails.

Consult the manual:

- https://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Side note: Using the `!` (NOT) operator, means if "not" empty which is what you want here.

Set those inside a conditional [`isset()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) also for a named submit button. Yours isn't named right now so you will need to give it a name.

Something else:

Add and `if/else`. If it shows that it was sent, then mail did its job.

```
if(mail("email@example.com", "Suporte Célere", $mensagem)){
    echo "Mail was sent.";
}else{
    echo "Error"; // check your logs
}
```

Comment: I think the line breaks should also be `\r\n` rather than just `\n`.

Comment: @kojow7 Good point but those are usually set inside the headers as shown in mail's manual https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php when there are multiple header declarations. They're just adding a new line in the body, not in the headers.

Comment: On that page it says in referring to the message itself: `Each line should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n). Lines should not be larger than 70 characters.`

Comment: @kojow7 sure, if it's a Windows based system. Did you not read the caution? Being **Caution** (Windows only).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the caution is talking about something completely different. That caution part is specifically talking about a line beginning with a period. Not the general email specification of the format of messages which should use \r\n as line breaks.

Comment: Have you read this user contributed note? https://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#121027 so for the moment, if this is really a Windows-based question, then the OP should update their post as to which OS this is riding on. This is "if and when" they ever show up or even read all this.

Comment: Thank you, it would seem you are correct. Unfortunately, the section in question does not make it clear enough that the \r\n is for Windows only also.

Comment: @kojow7 You're welcome. Well, I believe that have been given more than enough information here in both the answer and comments. The ball is in their court, as it were. *Cheers*